# How in ruby delete all non-digits symbols (except commas and dashes)

Tags: ruby, regex

I meet some hard task for me. I has a string which need to parse into array and some other elements. I have a troubles with **REGEXP** so wanna ask help.

I need delete from string *all non-digits, except commas (,) and dashes (-)*

**For example:**

```
"!1,2e,3,6..-10" => "1,2,3,6-10"
"ffff5-10...." => "5-10"
"1.2,15" => "12,15"
```

and so.

Comment: Why do you assume this requires the use of a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"!1,2e,3,6..-10".gsub(/[^\d,-]+/, '') # => "1,2,3,6-10"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[^0-9,-]+
```

This should do it for you.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/44

Answer (score 2):

We must have at least one non-regex solution:

```
def keep_some(str, keepers)
  str.delete(str.delete(keepers))
end

keep_some("!1,2e,3,6..-10", "0123456789,-")
  #=> "1,2,3,6-10" 
keep_some("ffff5-10....", "0123456789,-")
  #=> "5-10"
keep_some("1.2,15", "0123456789,-")
  #=> "12,15"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a pattern that matches everything except what you want to keep, and replace it with the empty string. In a reguar expression, the [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^whatever]` matches everything *except* the characters in the "whatever", so this works:

```
a_string.gsub /[^0-9,-]/, ''
```

Note that the hyphen has to come last, as otherwise it will be interpreted as a range indicator.

To demonstrate, I put all your "before" strings into an Array and used [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to run the above `gsub` call on all of them, producing an Array of the "after" strings:

```
["!1,2e,3,6..-10", "ffff5-10....", "1.2,15"].map { |s| s.gsub /[^0-9,-]/, '' }

# => ["1,2,3,6-10", "5-10", "12,15"]
```